# Get Facebook user's page likes iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-page

I am making an iOS application where I want to get the list of all the pages that has been liked by the Facebook user. I have already used the permission 'user_likes' using Facebook Graph API. Now I want to display it.

Refer this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/object/likes

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer and this is how I made it happen:

```
                         //Page likes
                         /* make the API call */

                         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/likes?limit=10"                                                          parameters:nil
                                                      HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                                               completionHandler:^(
                                                                   FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                   id result,
                                                                   NSError *error
                                                                   ) {
                                                   /* handle the result */


                                                                    NSLog(@"Likes are:\n\n%@",result);

                                               }];







                         NSString *fbCountry=[
```